# Populating a dojo dijit/form/FilteringSelect with an Ajax response text

Tags: javascript, ajax, select, dojo

I have two drop downs in my application: to the first drop down (select type of institution), i've attached an onchange event that calls a javascript function (this one makes an ajax call) that is to populate the second drop down (select name of institution).
The HTML code looks like this:

```
<label for="typeHighInst">Type of institution: </label>
          <select data-dojo-type="dijit/form/FilteringSelect" data-dojo-id="typeHighInst" id="typeHighInst" name="typeHighInst" onChange="getInstitution(this.value)">
            <option value="" selected='selected'>-- select institution type -- </option>
            <?php foreach($InstitutionType as $institutiontype): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $institutiontype['TypeID']; ?>"><?php echo $institutiontype['Description'];  ?>
            </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
          </select>
<label for="nameHighInst">Name of institution: </label>
          <select data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select" data-dojo-id="nameHighInst" id="nameHighInst" name="nameHighInst">
            <option value="" selected='selected'>-- select institution --</option>
          </select>
```

The javascript code looks like this:

```
function getInstitution(str)
{
  var xmlhttp;

if (str=="")
{
    document.getElementById("nameHighInst").innerHTML="<option value='' selected='selected'>-- select institution --</option>";
    return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    document.getElementById("nameHighInst").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

  xmlhttp.open("GET","includes/getInstitution.php?typeHighInst="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The problem is that when you choose one option from the first drop down (e.g. University), the second drop down list is still empty (instead of showing list of all universities returned by ajax).

However, when I use the native select tag with the second drop down, all works fine (the select object is effectively populated with the list of all universities).

This is the code using the native select element:

```
<label for="nameHighInst">Name of institution: </label>
          <select id="nameHighInst" name="nameHighInst">
            <option value="" selected='selected'>-- select institution --</option>
          </select>
```

Can someone please tell me why it works with the native select element and not with the dijit/form/FilteringSelect widget? I'm a dojo newbie.
I would also like to know how to fix it. Though the native select works, i prefer using dojo widgets since i discovered them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the dojo object to manipulate the list:

```
  var dojo_obj = dijit.byId("nameHighInst");
  dojo_obj.attr("innerHTML",xmlhttp.responseText);
```

instead of

```
  document.getElementById("nameHighInst").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

What I think you want is this:

```
  var dojo_obj = dijit.byId("nameHighInst");
  dojo_obj.attr("options",xmlhttp.responseText);
```

xmlhttp.responseText for options should be in a JSON format:

```
options: [
  { label: 'TN', value: 'Tennessee' },
  { label: 'VA', value: 'Virginia', selected: true },
  { label: 'WA', value: 'Washington' },
  { label: 'FL', value: 'Florida' },
  { label: 'CA', value: 'California' }
]
```

Example:  http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/form/Select.html

Do the same when getting values from a dojo object:

```
  var dojo_obj = dijit.byId("nameHighInst");
  var val = dojo_obj.attr("value");
  var html = dojo_obj.attr("innerHTML");
  var options = dojo_obj.attr("options");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it's still not working. I suspect the problem is with the xmlhttp.responseText. this is what it returns:

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it's still not working for me. I suspect the problem is with the xmlhttp.responseText. this is what it returns:      { 
"options": [
{"label": "ABU", "value": "Ahmadu Bello University"},
{"label": "ASUU", "value": "Abia State University Uturu"},
{"label": "UC", "value": "University of Calabar"},
{"label": "UI", "value": "University of Ibadan"},
{"label": "", "value": "-- select institution --"}
]
}

Comment: I would modify the AJAX response to remove options, which is the name of the property:  "{ "options":".  Remove the last curly brace too. So, it should look like this: [ {"label": "ABU", "value": "Ahmadu Bello University"}, {"label": "ASUU", "value": "Abia State University Uturu"}, {"label": "UC", "value": "University of Calabar"}, {"label": "UI", "value": "University of Ibadan"}, {"label": "", "value": "-- select institution --"} ]            Keep an eye out for javascript errors...

Comment: I actually tried that one first without success. But since most of the documentation I have about JSON format recommend that we should start with an opening curly brace ({) and end with a closing curly brace, I decided to add {"options": but this one also did not work. In both cases, the typeof returns string instead of object which I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of achieving it

First of all dojo will parse your html content onload and then any changes to the inner html of any of the dijit elements will not reflect unless you manually parse it.

if you stick to the html way of changing the options you will have to call

```
dojo.parser.parse("id of enclosing div");
```

OR

Using dojo.attr

get the options in JSON format from your ajax response.

```
    var option = [{
        label: 'TN',
        value: 'Tennessee'
    },
    {
        label: 'VA',
        value: 'Virginia',
    }]

selectObj = dijit.byId("id of element");
selectObj.attr("options",option);
```

OR

set value of options directly using javascript instead of using .attr function and then restart the component.

```
selectObj.options = option;//JSON object
selectObj.restart();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it's still not working for me. I suspect the problem is with the xmlhttp.responseText. this is what it returns:      { 
"options": [
{"label": "ABU", "value": "Ahmadu Bello University"},
{"label": "ASUU", "value": "Abia State University Uturu"},
{"label": "UC", "value": "University of Calabar"},
{"label": "UI", "value": "University of Ibadan"},
{"label": "", "value": "-- select institution --"}
]
}     which is a string. I tried to convert it into a JSON object without success

Comment: The response seems correct yes you need to create a JSOn object out of this string what function did you try.

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(string)
var option = jsonObj.options //this should work

Comment: this is what i did:                                                 var option = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
var dojo_obj = dijit.byId("nameHighInst");
dojo_obj.attr("options",option); and it's still not working. Am I missing something?                                                      I also tried                                                               var option = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);                         selectObj.options = option;                                                      selectObj.restart(); without success

Comment: your response is a JSON response with key as options. you need to fech the value corresponding to that key. In the code you pasted above try

 var option = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText); var dojo_obj = dijit.byId("nameHighInst"); dojo_obj.attr("options",option.options);

or alternatively 

 var option = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText); selectObj.options = option.options; selectObj.restart();

Comment: one step ahead, but not there yet. i could finally convert my response into a JSON object; i figured out i first needed to convert my returned string text into a javascript STRING object. however, the values of the json object are still not populated in the FilteringSelect. This is what the new code looks like:              var stringOption = xmlhttp.responseText;
var stringobjectOption = new String(stringOption);
var jsonobjectOption = JSON.parse(stringobjectOption);
var dojo_obj = dijit.byId("nameHighInst");
dojo_obj.attr("options",jsonobjectOption.options);

Comment: when you are using dojo why not use dojo.xhrGet for your ajax calls. the function gives an option to read the response as text/html ot JSON. so u can go away with a lot of extra code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I wasn't aware of this function. I'll read about it and apply it to my project, then tell you what i got.